# Obligar a los usuarios huawei a actualizar app

Tags: xamarin

Alguien podria ayudarme explicandome que codigo podria utilizar para obligar a los usuarios a actualizar app desde xamarin?
especificamente para usuarios Huawei, y la AppGallery

Comment: hola, has buscado en internet posibles soluciones? probado algún código? nosotros te podemos ayudar pero la idea es que tú ya hayas probado algo y en base a eso, si tienes errores en el código, te podemos dar posibles soluciones a tu problema. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.